# Car engine stutters when hot, and sometimes stalls

Tags: ignition, suzuki, rough-idle, swift

My car (Suzuki Swift 1999, engine G10A 1.0) stutters and jerks when hot, after driving for like 10 to 15 minutes the problem arise. The strange thing is that when this happens and i turn off the engine and try to start it again it wont start for like a minute, after that the engine starts and runs fine for another 5 a 10 minutes before the stuttering and jerking problem comes back.

I replaced the ignition coil and the Ignition Control Module, the stuttering is way less serve but its still there.

Any ideas what can be wrong ?

Comment: Get a scanner and log some fuel pressure times if you have that PID available. Or try physically connecting a fuel pressure gauge and see what you measure. I had a car that jerked and hesitated when the engine was warm, turned out to be a bad fuel pressure sensor that eventually triggered a CEL that keyed me on to it. Get some propane and a hose and snoop around for vacuum leaks too.

Comment: Maybe evaporative system issue perhaps? I had a similar issue with a Corolla ...never solved the problem. Traded in on a new vehicle. Sorry no help here.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone reading this. I had water in my gasoline tank.